# andorid app UI not updating in realtime when data change in firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an android app called [UMoney](https://github.com/yashkite/UMoney/tree/Dev), I have encountered the [bug](https://github.com/yashkite/UMoney/issues/24) in which the app UI not updating in realtime when data changes in firestore, I'm using FirebaseUI and their classes to extend my classes, I have tried building using inbuild stock android RecyclerView classes but it's not working and then I tried FirebaseUI. you can read about the issues in detail [here](https://github.com/yashkite/UMoney/issues/24)

Comment: Show us the code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: @AlexMamo i have hyperlinked the project and issue, can you visit them if your comfortable, because I don't know which part i should share, it confuses me